# Nickelodeon special with puppets as "Goblins", looking for a crown

Tags: story-identification, tv, magic, magical-creatures

This show was a late 80s/early 90s **Nickelodeon** or **Nick Jr.** special, utlizing puppets and live action cast members. It definitely wasn’t *The Dark Crystal*. As I remember it, the basic premise was as follows:

Two factions of Goblins are trying to choose a king, and to do so they have to get a special crown before the end of one particular day. This day is the only time in which the crown can be touched, as Goblins can usually only move at night; if they are exposed to sunlight on any other day, they will turn to stone. The current king and his son are trying to claim the crown before the leader of the evil faction and his son find it. Somehow, a human boy became involved. At the end, the evil father and son are turned to stone.

Comment: it's different enough that it likely isn't The Dark Crystal, but....one could see how a fuzzy memory of Dark Crystal could become this

Comment: oh not, it is DEFINITELY *8not** the Dark Crystal; I'm a Jim Henson _superfan_ and have seen that movie multiple times. This wasn;t a "Major motion picture" kind of film, more like a "muppets halloween special" kind of thing. I can't say for certain that Henson and his people weren;t involved, however, because the quality of puppeting _was_ rather well done. And it wasn't an episode of **The Stroy Teller** either; it took place in modern times, with the direct action of a human boy, and no cut-away segments. and there were no skesix to be seen

Comment: Maybe this was one of the stories contained within the series: “The Third Eye”? - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Third_Eye_(TV_series)

Comment: Does the phrase "Bake the hall on the candle of her brain" fit here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [**The Crown of Bogg**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0185059/), a 30-minute special from 1981. From IMDb:

> **It is time to crown a new king of the kingdom of Bogg, and King Mildew's son, Milo, seems like the best creature for the job. However, Vandred, the king's brother, has other plans, and intends to put his son, Vandal, on the thrown. He challenges Milo, who must prove his worthiness by retrieving the Crown of Bogg and returning it to the kingdom.** The crown has been banned from the kingdom for years because it is cursed, but Mildew and Milo are willing to face the risks of the quest in order to keep Vandred and Vandal from assuming control of the kingdom. **But in order to retrieve the crown, they will have to leave Bogg and go to The Surface...where the humans are.**

It's live-action with puppet creatures that are Henson-esque, but this is actually a Paul Fusco production (he created [*ALF*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALF_(TV_series))). It ends like you described (the evil father and son run outside and turn to stone). It's currently available in its entirety on Youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkKDGqOI8W4), and here's that ending:

Comment: This definitely looks like it.... Thank you! I'll take a watch and let you know later.

Comment: viewed it. Yep, this is it. Thank you!